# How to change background color by clicking on a button using JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom, dom-events, addeventlistener

When I click on the button for the first time it changes the bg color but after that, if I click on the button again, the color won't change

Here is my script :

```js
colors = ["#8E44AD", "#3498DB", "#1ABC9C", "#F1C40F", "#839192", "#FF0096", "#15FF00"];
var a = document.querySelector("body");
var b = document.querySelector("button");
b.addEventListener("click",changeColor);

function changeColor()
{
    for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++)
    {
        a.style.backgroundColor = colors[i]
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
 <button>Change BG Color</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This code cycles through all of the colors in the loop synchronously and always set the last color in the array as the final background color when the stack empties and the next rerender runs. What logic did you intend? If you want to step forward one element per click, get rid of the loop, move the `i` counter outside of the function (best to use a closure) and increment it once per call. Use modulus to wrap around if desired. Or rotate the array with `colors.push(colors.shift())` and always set the background color to `colors[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works.
Each time the button is clicked, it sets the background color of the body element to the last color in the array colors.

So the second time you click the button, since you once again set the background color of the body element to the last color in the array colors, you don't notice a difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 0;
function changeColor()
{
  a.style.backgroundColor = colors[count%colors.length];
  count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every thing seems correct but your changeColor function seems to be weird.
This function will loop through all the colors in array and end up giving the last color of the array to body background.
Here are my solution for this types of problem.

I will Change only changeColor function since other codes are correct.

1> If you want to change color in array in order:

```
function changeColor() = {
   let i = 0;
   if(i === colors.length){
       a.style.background = colors[i];
       i = 0;
   } else{
      a.style.background = colors[i];
   }
}
```

I think it will work....But If you want to randomly give colors from array then follow following code:

```
function changeColor(){
    randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length - 1);
     a.style.background = colors[randNum];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you will see the color changes.

```js
colors = ["#8E44AD", "#3498DB", "#1ABC9C", "#F1C40F", "#839192", "#FF0096", "red"];
var a = document.querySelector("div");
var b = document.querySelector("button");
b.addEventListener("click",changeColor);

async function changeColor()
{
  for(let i=0; i<colors.length; i++) {
    a.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    await delay(1000);
  }
}

function delay(delayInms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('waiting...')
      resolve(2);
    }, delayInms);
  });
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>test</button>
</div>
```